# fetch mysql result in batch shell

Tags: mysql, shell, batch-file

i'm trying to create a batch script to do some actions in my mysql database and some other actions with linux command, I'm trying to fetch result from my query to mysql in my script to put the result in an associative array, I've found just how to do it in simple array for one column, here is my query:

```
result=`mysql -h $DATABASE_HOST --user=$DATABASE_USER --password=$DATABASE_PASSWORD --skip-column-names -s -e "select id,type from $DATABASE_NAME.Media where status=0 "
```

I'm not an expert in batch script, sorry if it is a noob question !

Comment: if this can help as a result for the query I have this: 1 type1 2 type2

Answer (score 0):

```
result=$(mysql ...)
declare -A ary
while read id type; do
    ary[$id]=$type
done <<< "$result"
```